# Need to run pip install --editable . to update the code

Tags: python, pip, python-behave

I'm playing a bit with [Behave's source code](https://github.com/behave/behave).

I've downloaded it with git:

`git clone  git@github.com:behave/behave.git`

Abd I'm installing it with pip:

```
cd behave
pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/git/behave
Requirement already satisfied: cucumber-tag-expressions>=1.1.2 in c:\users\my_user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from behave==1.2.7.dev2) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: parse>=1.18.0 in c:\users\my_user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from behave==1.2.7.dev2) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parse_type>=0.4.2 in c:\users\my_user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from behave==1.2.7.dev2) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\my_user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from behave==1.2.7.dev2) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\my_user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from behave==1.2.7.dev2) (0.4.4)
Installing collected packages: behave
  Attempting uninstall: behave
    Found existing installation: behave 1.2.7.dev2
    Uninstalling behave-1.2.7.dev2:
      Successfully uninstalled behave-1.2.7.dev2
  Running setup.py develop for behave
Successfully installed behave
```

However, if I add a print call anywhere, I can only see it printing something if I re-run `pip install -e .`. I'm a bit at a loss here, I've always used `pip install -e .` and any code changes were immediately picked up when I re-ran my application.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip install -e .`?

Comment: `pip install -e .` and `python -m pip install -e .` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of pip seems correct.  I use `pip install -e .` all the time as well.

The problem may be related to your environment:

- Try `which python` or `where python` and make sure you don't get a surprising result.
- Run `pip list` and `python -m pip list` and make sure the results match.
- Create a new environment (`python -m venv /path/for/virtual-environment`), and try to install only the package/dependencies you need.

If the problem is not with your environment, it may be with your implementation of behave.

If you're not doing so already, you may try changing your import statements to see if you get different results:

```
from behave import step_registry
```

vs.

```
from behave.step_registry import step_impl
```

vs.

```
from behave import *
```

I have found that python packages are sometimes very particular about the way that you import objects, and using alternative import statements can reveal some surprising behavior.